# Определить кнопку, которую я нажал

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

Нужно сделать, чтобы JS определял, на какой конкретно *example__item* я нажал, и использовал значения, находящиеся конкретно в нажатом объекте. При этом код не должен опираться на порядок элементов в HTML. Как это реализовать?

P.S. Намереваюсь сделать возможность открывать модальные окна у объектов в Slick слайдере, в которых будут содержаться уникальные подробные данные о выбранном элементе.

```
<div class="example">
    <div class="example__item">Значение 1</div>
    <div class="example__item">Значение 2</div>
    <div class="example__item">Значение 3</div>
    <div class="example__item">Значение 4</div>
    <div class="example__item">Значение 5</div>
    <div class="example__item">Значение 6</div>
    <div class="example__item">Значение 7</div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/event-delegation

Comment: "Код не должен опираться на порядок элементов" — А на что? Текст внутри?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

я очень уважаю вариант коллеги *Daniil Screpchenko*, но я бы не советовал так делать, так как вы вешаете **на каждый элемент** по обработчику (по мотивам производительности).
достаточно было бы повесить **один** обработчик только на родителя. к примеру:

```
document.querySelector('.example').addEventListener('click', event => {
  event.target.innerHTML = "It's me!";
});
```

c Уважением

Comment: А пробовали сравнить эту самую "производительность" ?) Если на 100,000 элементов циклом навешивать обработчики - на всё про всё и правда уходит аж 1 секунда. С делегированием - почти ничто. Но когда всё отработало - во время самого клика нет никакой разницы.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const example = document.querySelector('.example');

example.addEventListener('click', e => {
  console.log(e.target);
});
```

```html
<div class="example">
  <div class="example__item">Значение 1</div>
  <div class="example__item">Значение 2</div>
  <div class="example__item">Значение 3</div>
  <div class="example__item">Значение 4</div>
  <div class="example__item">Значение 5</div>
  <div class="example__item">Значение 6</div>
  <div class="example__item">Значение 7</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let example = document.querySelector('.example');

example.addEventListener('click', function(e){
  let target = e.target;
  console.log( target.innerHTML )
})
```

```css
.example__item{
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="example">
  <div class="example__item">Значение 1</div>
  <div class="example__item">Значение 2</div>
  <div class="example__item">Значение 3</div>
  <div class="example__item">Значение 4</div>
  <div class="example__item">Значение 5</div>
  <div class="example__item">Значение 6</div>
  <div class="example__item">Значение 7</div>
</div>
```